# How can I set a Boolean value in jQuery based on an input of type radio?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, radio-button, splistitem

I have a pair of inputs of type radio like so:

```
<label>YES</label>
<input type="radio" name="uscitizen" id="uscitizenyes" value="YES" required />
<label>NO</label>
<input type="radio" name="uscitizen" id="uscitizenno" value="NO" />
```

To set the value of a Sharepoint 2010 List item ('ptli_USCitizen' in this case), is this the best way to accomplish it:

```
oListItem.set_item('ptli_USCitizen', ($('uscitizenyes').val() == 'YES'));
```

...or is there a more "accepted patternful" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
oListItem.set_item('ptli_USCitizen', ($('[name="uscitizen"]:checked').val() == 'YES'));
```

But the best way to handle a boolean value in the User Interface is a Checkbox rather than radio buttons.

```
Us Citizen: <input type='checkbox' id='uscitizen' name='uscitizen' />
```

Then use:

```
oListItem.set_item('ptli_USCitizen', ($('#uscitizen').is(':checked'));
```

Comment: Thanks; I don't control what the UI looks like, though.

Answer (score 3):

Can use the `:checked` selector

```
$('[name=uscitizenyes]:checked').val()
```

Assumes you want the value for your list as opposed to boolean shown in question

```
oListItem.set_item('ptli_USCitizen',$('[name=uscitizenyes]:checked').val())
```

For boolean can use the ID for YES and `is(':checked')`

```
oListItem.set_item('ptli_USCitizen',$('#uscitizenyes').is(':checked'))
```

Comment: I assume this (referencing the element's ID instead of name) will work for radio buttons that are part of a group, and thus share the same name:
$('#visitor:checked').val());

Comment: Depends what you want...booolean or value... ID's must be unique is why I used name to get value and added another with ID for boolean

Comment: now realizing I completely missed `boolean` in subject

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get a bool result without the explicit need for checking for YES.

```
$('#radio_button').is(':checked')
```

Comment: this won't work with the html shown in the question.

Comment: It was more meant like a general answer to cleanly retrieve a bool val for a radio button.